# GROUP BY invalid when upgraded MySQL version

Tags: mysql

When I upgraded my ubuntu from 15.10 to 16.04 I have this error in my yii project:

> CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[42000]:
>   Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column
>   'v4master.A.id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in
>   GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with
>   sql_mode=only_full_group_by. The SQL statement executed was:

The sql code is follows:

```
 $sql = "SELECT A.*,B.`type_name` FROM `".$this->tbl_auth_user_items."` A 
                INNER JOIN `".$this->tbl_auth_context_types."` B ON A.`type_id` = B.`type_id` 
                WHERE A.`user_id` = '".$user_id."' GROUP BY A.`type_id`, A.`type_value` ORDER BY A.`type_id` DESC";
         return $this->_db->createCommand($sql)->queryAll();
```

Comment: check if the database version  is 5.7 or above  ..  because starting for mysql 5.7 the use of column in select without aggreation function  and not mentioned  in group by is not allowed  by default

Comment: Invalid group by. Won't execute on newer MySQL versions (unless in compatibility mode), may return unpredictable results with older MySQL versions. The general GROUP BY rule says: If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run this query at Mysql;

```
set global sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';
```

Comment: if($this->persistentConnection !== false)  $this->_mongoConnection = new Mongo($this->connectionString, array('connect'=>$this->autoConnect,
                         'persist'=>$this->persistentConnection                     ));
               else
                    $this->_mongoConnection = new Mongo($this->connectionString, array(
                         'connect'=>$this->autoConnect,
                     ));

                 return $this->_mongoConnection;
            }

Comment: you should install php-mongo-driver, then add extension=mongo.so or extension=mongodb.so library into php.ini file

Comment: tar zxvf mongodb-mongodb-php-driver-<commit_id>.tar.gz which commit id is to be given

Answer (score 0):

Coild that your upgrade implies also a db upgrade to mysql 5.7 if so  you must know that 
starting for mysql 5.7 the use of column in select without aggreation function and not mentioned in group by is not allowed by default

if you need distinct result set  ypu should use `distinct` clause and not group by

```
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT 
        A.*,B.`type_name` 
        FROM `".$this->tbl_auth_user_items."` A 
        INNER JOIN `".$this->tbl_auth_context_types."` B ON A.`type_id` = B.`type_id` 
        WHERE A.`user_id` = '".$user_id."' 
        ORDER BY A.`type_id` DESC";
     return $this->_db->createCommand($sql)->queryAll();
```

or ( but is deprecated) you can change the sql_mode for reverting to the previuos version behavior

fro

```
 sql_mode = 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY';
```

to

```
 SET sql_mode = ''
```

Comment: Working but group by clause is required

Comment: i have alredy update the answer  with the suggestion for reveting the sql_mode to the version before mysql 5.7 ...  if you need group by (because you are using improperly)   you could use  this  ..but a query with group by and not aggregation function is depreacted  in most sql  database  .. so you should rethink your query ..

Comment: tar zxvf mongodb-mongodb-php-driver-<commit_id>.tar.gz which commit id is to be given